How to Manually Track a Custom Key That Involves Interpolation in String Catalog (Localizable.xcstrings)
In SwiftUI (although this question may apply to a wider domain than that),
If you are localizing your app with the latest methods, then you are using String Catalogs (Localizable.xcstrings)
Normally (as they seem to not mention any other option in this video), strings are automatically "picked up" in your codebase and put in your string catalog, so if you had:
Text("this is some string about an arbitrary thing that could be an any length that begins with any letter") 

in your code, you would see a new entry in your string catalog with a key AND value of "this is some string about an arbitrary thing that could be an any length that begins with any letter".
Now, I don't happen to like that and I prefer to have a manual custom key like "main_add_link_label" because that just makes more sense to me for many many reasons.
So that's what I've done so far, but then I ran into the issue of something like this:
Text("\(numSessions) Sessions")

Where there is interpolation involved.
I understand how this would work if I were content to leave the code alone and have this one automatically tracked, but...
What is the proper way to implement and access custom string catalog keys that involve interpolation?
Do we still need to use something like:
Text(String(format: NSLocalizedString("session_count", comment: ""), numSessions))

?  Hopefully something nicer is possible.

I have a solution and its advantage is you can use manual custom key like "main_add_link_label" or use strings that are automatically "picked up" in your codebase and put in your string catalog.
You can create a custom SwiftUI view like this -
import Foundation
typealias Function = (String, [CVarArg]) -> String
let LocalizeString = unsafeBitCast(String.init(format:_:), to: Function.self)

struct Localize: View {
    var text: String
    var arg: Any?
    var body: some View {
        if let arg = arg {
            if let args = arg as? [CVarArg] {
                Text(LocalizeString(text, args).replacingOccurrences(of: "(null)", with: ""))
            } else {
                Text(String(format: NSLocalizedString(text, comment: ""), arg as! any CVarArg))
            }
        } else {
            Text(LocalizedStringKey(text))
        }
    }
}

and use it like below instead of Text("\(numSessions) Sessions")
For plain text
Localize(text: "this is some string about an arbitrary thing")

Output - this is some string about an arbitrary thing

For interger
Localize(text: "%d Sessions", arg: 4)

Output - 4 Sessions

For string
Localize(text: "%@ sessions", arg: "four")

Output - four sessions

For integer and strings interpolated in one
Localize(text: "%d sessions will cost %d %@", arg: [4, 100, "dollars"])

Output - 4 sessions will cost 100 dollars


You should avoid caring about the keys. Interpolation is central to the implementation.
extension LocalizedStringKey {
    static func mainAddLinkLabel(_ numSessions: Int) -> LocalizedStringKey {
        "\(numSessions) Sessions"
    }
}


Text(.mainAddLinkLabel(numSessions))

The key will still be the string, but you can use whatever name you want for your functions or lets. You can also nest enums to have name spaces.
Text(.Home.navigationTitle)

If you’re still intent on going with a custom key, I’d recommend using String(localized:), and its overloads. That’s the modern equivalent of the old way.


My solution is not standard way.
My solution is absolutely not a best practice.
But I believe that its much better than absolutely native swiftUIs way for some cases.


I use keys like this:
"main.title"
"main.timeLeft.%lld"     // 1 value in the end of the key
"main.summary.%lld.%lld" // 2 values separated with dots

in dictionary you will see sth like this:
//en
"main.title" = "My awesome app"
"main.timeLeft.%lld" = "%lld sec time left"
"main.summary.%lld.%lld" = "Summary: %1$lld hrs %2$lld mins"

//uk
"main.title" = "Моя прекрасна програма"
"main.timeLeft.%lld" = "Залишилося %lld секунд"
// Important to see here that `%lld` located in different places 
// of translations - on the beginning of the string and in the 
// middle of the string.
"main.summary.%lld.%lld" = "Cумарно %1$lld:%2$lld"

also in translation of summary you can see %1$lld:%2$lld - you can move each value from one place to another in your string.
So I'm using this keys like this:
Text("main.title")

Text("main.timeLeft.\(timeLeft)")

Text("main.summary.\(value1).\(value2)")

//also if I don't want to create value in my localization files I've using "verbatim" initializer like this:
Text(verbatim: "\(someTimeInSeconds)")

and in most cases this is enough.

But this system is not smart enough for me!

In some cases I need to force some exact locale without change of OS locale.
In some cases I need to get translation from key. Like write key in enum's rawValue or sth like this.
I need to force ENG localization in case of another translation is not accessible for this key. But I do not want to use english sentence as a key.

So in this cases I'm using custom extensions in some places like this:
Text(verbatim: "main.title".localized )
Text(verbatim: "main.timeLeft.%lld".localized(timeLeft) )
Text(verbatim: "main.summary.%lld.%lld".localized(value1, value2) )

and forcing locale for window like this:
MyMainView()
   .forceLocale(Config.shared.currLang.value)

My extensions:
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

#if DEBUG
// nil = system locale
// "En" = english
// "Uk" = ukrainian
// "Ge" = german
public var forceCurrentLocale: String? = nil
#else
public var forceCurrentLocale: String? = nil
#endif

public extension String {
    var localized: String {
        return localizedString(for: self, locale: chooseLocale(nil) )
    }
    
    func localized(_ params: CVarArg...) -> String {
        localized(locale: nil, params)
    }
    
    func localized(locale: Locale?, _ params: CVarArg...) -> String {
        let key: String = self
        let locale: Locale = chooseLocale(locale)
        
        let currentLocaleValue = localizedString(for: key, locale: locale, params: params)
        
        //if we have no translation for this language, we return Eng
        if currentLocaleValue == key {
            let engLocaleValue = localizedString(for: key, locale: Locale(identifier: "en"), params: params)
            
            return params.count > 0
                    ? String.localizedStringWithFormat(engLocaleValue, params)
                    : engLocaleValue
        }
        
        // in another case return valuse for curr lang
        return currentLocaleValue
    }
}

fileprivate func localizedString(for key: String, locale: Locale = .current, params: CVarArg...) -> String {
    let language = locale.languageCode
    guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: language, ofType: "lproj") ?? Bundle.main.path(forResource: "en", ofType: "lproj") else {
        let error = "LOCALIZTION ERROR: \(locale.identifier), key:\(key)"
//        printDbg(error)
        return error
    }
    
    let bundle = Bundle(path: path)!
    let localizedStr = NSLocalizedString(key, bundle: bundle, comment: "")
    let formattedLocalizedStr = String(format: localizedStr, params)
    
    return formattedLocalizedStr
}

fileprivate func chooseLocale(_ locale: Locale?) -> Locale {
    if let locale {
        return locale
    }
    
    if let forceCurrentLocale {
        return Locale.init(identifier: forceCurrentLocale)
    } else {
        return Locale.current
    }
}

extension Locale {
    static var en: Locale { Locale(identifier: "en") }
    static var uk: Locale { Locale(identifier: "uk") }
    static var ru: Locale { Locale(identifier: "ru") }
}

public extension View {
    @ViewBuilder
    func forceLocale(_ locale: String? ) -> some View {
        if let locale {
            self.environment(\.locale, Locale(identifier: locale))
        } else {
            self
        }
    }
}

